# Conflicting partition column names detected Pyspark Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, partitioning, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to read a csv file with pyspark in databricks.
marketingStartDate is this format `yyyyMMdd` and `lastweek = marketingStartDate -7days`

```
readFactToDataFrame('Facts', 
'Fact.csv',startDate=str(dateBefore),
           endDate=str(marketingStartDate),
           inferSchema=False)
```

I am getting this error message. Do you have any idea where the problem lies ?

[image]

```
df = spark.read.format(fileFormat).options(header=True, inferSchema=
inferSchema, delimiter = columnDelimiter).load(URL).filter("Year *
10000 + Month * 100 + Day = "+str(startDate) + " AND Year * 10000 +
Month * 100 + Day <=" + str(endDate)) 37 elif fileFormat == "json": 38
df =
spark.read.format(fileFormat).options(multiline=True).load(URL).filter("Year
* 10000 + Month * 100 + Day = "+str(startDate) + " AND Year * 10000 + Month * 100 + Day <=" + str(endDate))
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path,
format, schema, **options) 164 self.options(**options) 165 if
isinstance(path, basestring): -- 166 return
self._df(self._jreader.load(path)) 167 elif path is not None: 168 if
type(path) != list:
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
in __call__(self, *args) 1255 answer =
self.gateway_client.send_command(command) 1256 return_value =
get_return_value( - 1257 answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id,
self.name) 1258 1259 for temp_arg in temp_args:
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw) 61 def
deco(*a, **kw): 62 try: --- 63 return f(*a, **kw) 64 except
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e: 65 s = e.java_exception.toString()
/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name) 326 raise
Py4JJavaError( 327 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n". --
328 format(target_id, ".", name), value) 329 else: 330 raise
Py4JError( Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2301.load.
: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting partition
column names detected: Partition column name list #0: Year, Month, Day
Partition column name list #1: Year, Month For partitioned table
directories, data files should only live in leaf directories. And
directories at the same level should have the same partition column
name. Please check the following directories for unexpected files or
inconsistent partition column names:
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=08
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=03/Day=16
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=09/Day=27
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=09/Day=02
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=08/Day=01
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=03/Day=09
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=02/Day=26
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=08/Day=10
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=09/Day=12
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=10/Day=12
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=03/Day=24
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=09/Day=05
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=03/Day=13
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=10/Day=27
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2019/Month=09/Day=16
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=02/Day=20
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=03/Day=31 at
scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170) at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.resolvePartitions(PartitioningUtils.scala:396)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.parsePartitions(PartitioningUtils.scala:197)
at
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningUtils$.parsePartitions(PartitioningUtils.scala:132)
```

Comment: what happens if you read it from source ? `spark.read.parquet('dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following error is thrown due to source location dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts has two different partition structure.

```
     java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Conflicting partition column names detected: 
Partition column name list #0: Year, Month, Day 
Partition column name list #1: Year, Month
```

Error details are pointing out to problematic directory:

```
dbfs:/mnt/DL/Facts/Year=2020/Month=08
```

Inspect above databricks directory to see if any files on this location. You can either remove them or move to some different directory.
If there is not files on above directory, you can remove directory itself.

I hope it helps to fix this issue.

Comment: yes there was an issue in the directory. Some files where directly put in the month folder